# django multiple user with multiple groups problem at signup

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

here is my problem, I created 3 groups with django admin panel ('admin', 'prof', 'etudiant' but I don't use the group admin for the moment). I created two model classes which inherit from the User model with oneToOneField ('Professeur' and 'Etudiant'). I also create a registration form for all two model classes.
Using django post_save I can register my different users with groups. but now if I try to register a new user 'Professeur' with its own register form for example it is automatically added to the two groups 'prof' and 'etudiant'.
what to do so that a user belongs to only one group

### etudiant/models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class Etudiant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    et_matricule_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^(ET)-[A-Z]{2}-(PM)-[\d]{4}$',
                                        message="ex: ET-AD-PM-2020 -> Etudiant - Ali Diop - Pierre Michel- 2020")
    et_numero_matricule = models.CharField(validators=[et_matricule_regex], max_length=40, unique=True,
                                           verbose_name="numéro matricule")
    et_lieu_de_residence = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, verbose_name="lieu de résidence")
    et_date_de_naissance = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="date de naissance")
    et_telephone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?[\d]{3}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}$',
                                        message="+000-00-00-00-00")
    et_telephone = models.CharField(validators=[et_telephone_regex], max_length=40, blank=True,
                                    verbose_name="telephone")
```

### professeur/models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class Professeur(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    prof_matricule_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^(PR)-[A-Z]{2}-(PM)-[\d]{4}$',
                                          message="ex: PR-ZT-PM-2017 -> Professeur - Zan Togola - Pierre Michel- 2017")
    prof_numero_matricule = models.CharField(validators=[prof_matricule_regex], max_length=40, unique=True,
                                             verbose_name="numéro matricule")
    prof_lieu_de_residence = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, verbose_name="lieu de résidence")
    prof_date_de_naissance = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="date de naissance")
    prof_telephone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?[\d]{3}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}$',
                                          message="+000-00-00-00-00")
    prof_telephone = models.CharField(validators=[prof_telephone_regex], max_length=30, blank=True,
                                      verbose_name="telephone")
```

### etudiant/signals.py

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Etudiant


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def etudiant_profil(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name='etudiant')
        instance.groups.add(group)

        Etudiant.objects.create(
            user=instance,
        )
```

### professeur/signals.py

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Professeur


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def professeur_profil(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name='prof')
        instance.groups.add(group)

        Professeur.objects.create(
            user=instance,
        )
```

### etudiant/apps.py

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class EtudiantConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'etudiant'

    def ready(self):
        import etudiant.signals # noqa
```

### professeur/apps.py

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ProfesseurConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'professeur'

    def ready(self):
        import professeur.signals # noqa
```

### etudiant/views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from compte.forms import CreateUserForm
from .forms import EtudiantForm
from compte.decorators import unauthenticated_user
from django.contrib import messages


@unauthenticated_user
def etudiantRegisterPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        etudiant_form = EtudiantForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and etudiant_form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            etudiant = etudiant_form.save(commit=False)
            etudiant.user = user

            etudiant.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Compte etudiant créer avec succès !')
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()
        etudiant_form = EtudiantForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'etudiant_form': etudiant_form
    }
    return render(request, 'registerEtudiant.html', context)
```

### professeur/views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ProfesseurForm
from compte.forms import CreateUserForm
from compte.decorators import unauthenticated_user
from django.contrib import messages


@unauthenticated_user
def professeurRegisterPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        professeur_form = ProfesseurForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and professeur_form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            professeur = professeur_form.save(commit=False)
            professeur.user = user

            professeur.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Compte professeur creer avec succès !')
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()
        professeur_form = ProfesseurForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'professeur_form': professeur_form
    }
    return render(request, 'registerProfesseur.html', context)
```

### Group

[Group screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Qhv.jpg)

### my forms

```py
#User creation form
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Mot de passe", widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'style': 'width: 100%;'}),
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Confirmation du mot de passe", widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'style': 'width: 100%;'}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email']
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width: 100%;'
            }),

            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width: 100%;'
            }),

            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width: 100%;'
            }),

            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width: 100%;'
            }),

        }


#Professeur creation form
class ProfesseurForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Professeur
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user']
        widgets = {
            'prof_numero_matricule': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width: 100%;'
            }),

            'prof_lieu_de_residence': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width: 100%;'
            }),

            'prof_date_de_naissance': forms.DateInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width: 100%;'
            }),

            'prof_telephone': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width: 100%;'
            }),

        }


#Etudiant creation form
class EtudiantForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Etudiant
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user']
        widgets = {
            'et_numero_matricule': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width: 100%;'
            }),

            'et_lieu_de_residence': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width: 100%;'
            }),

            'et_date_de_naissance': forms.DateInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width: 100%;'
            }),

            'et_telephone': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width: 100%;'
            }),

        }
```

Comment: Can you show your forms? Just wondering why you save the form say for `Etudiant` in the views which should have created the `Etudiant` instance, and then create 
 one again in the signal receiver?

Comment: ok i will edit and show the forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused because the signal sender is the `User` model itself. So saving the user instance of one of the profiles will call both the `professeur_profil` and `etudiant_profil` receivers. One approach to fix this is to change the senders of the receivers to the profile model instead:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Professeur)
def professeur_profil(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name='prof')
        instance.user.groups.add(group)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Etudiant)
def etudiant_profil(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name='etudiant')
        instance.user.groups.add(group)
```

Comment: if I do that the program tells me : AttributeError at /compte/register/

'Professeur' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: Don't forget it should be `instance.user.groups` and not `instance.groups`